# Graphs and cycles

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If we have a connected graph $G(V,E)$. Now I want to prove that if $\{a,b \} \in E$ is in a cycle $\iff G \backslash \{a,b\}$ is connected.

Proving the second direction is easier

If $G \backslash \{a,b \}$is connected, then this means that there exists a path between any two vertices in $G \backslash \{a,b \}$, 
and so adding $ \{a,b \}$ will just add a cycle. The result is obvious but I think I need a rigorous proof here.

For the other direction,

if the edge $ \{a,b \}$ is in a cycle, then how can I argue that removing it will guarantee that the graph is still connected.

First I assume that $ \{a, b \}$is in a cycle, Now imagine that there are two vertices in this cycle $x,y$. Since they are in this cycle then there must exists a path between them but then removing the edge $\{a, b\}$ will do what then ? I am confused here

Answer (score 1):

In a cycle $v_1$,$v_2$,.....,$v_n$ there always exists atleast two paths between any pair of vertices. Hence deleting an edge $(a,b)$ will produce an *open path* which is connected.